# Validate the cell value when lose focus

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

All, I want to catch the event after I finish input the value of `DataGridView` cell so that I can validate the value. Is there any event `DataGridView` when focus-lose happen? What is the best way to make it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CellValidating` event for this, see here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx).

> Occurs when a cell loses input focus, enabling content validation.

and example (from MSDN as well)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
    int newInteger;

    // Don't try to validate the 'new row' until finished  
    // editing since there 
    // is not any point in validating its initial value. 
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) { return; }
    if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(),
        out newInteger) || newInteger < 0)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "the value must be a non-negative integer";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to restore the original value when the validation doesn't pass. How to make it . thanks.

Comment: You have to implement such functionality yourself unfortunately.